# Ajax or jquery client side crop and resize library which sends the cropped file to server with http request

Tags: php, jquery, image, upload, crop

I am planning to use it for uploading user pictures and saving thumbnail copies. I am using php for handling files.

My request is, please link me to some libraries or plug ins.

Comment: This is far, far easier to do server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCrop for the client, PHP/GD for the server.

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

The JQuery handles the cropping, the Php the actual resizing.